# Sencha: scrollable vbox layout with a tabpanel inside

Tags: layout, sencha-touch-2

I just started working with Sencha Touch 2.3.

I've got a NavigationView. 
Inside of it there is a View (layout: 'vbox') composed by two panel (flex: 0) and one tabpanel (flex: 1). The View should be entirely scrollable.

The problem is that the content of the tabpanel is not entirely visible and not fill the entire page.

If the layout property of the tabpanel is set to 'fit' it's content is show properly, the entire view scroll as aspected but the tabpanel stop working. Same result if I put the tabpanel inside an outer container and set to it 'layout: fit'.

This is an extract of my code:

```
Ext.define('App.view.athletes.Detail', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'athleteDetail',

config: {
    itemId: 'view-athleteDetail',
    title: '...',
    layout: 'vbox',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'component-wrapper',
            scrollable: true,
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside of 'component-wrapper' I dynamically create and add the 3 components described above:

```
this.topComponent = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        flex: 0,
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [
            {
            xtype: 'panel',
            ....
            ....
            },
            {
            xtype: 'panel',
            ....
            ....
            }
        ]
});

this.baseInfoComponent = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    flex: 0,
    html: '...'
});


this.bottomComponent = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
        flex: 1,
        tabBarPosition: 'top',
        styleHtmlContent : true,

        items: [
            {
            ........
            },
            {
            ........
            }
        ]
});
```

Thanx in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "component-wrapper" panel. And add those dynamic panels inside "view-athleteDetails". For understanding, try this:

```
 config: {
        cls: 'main',
        itemId: 'view-athleteDetail',
        title: '...',
        layout: 'vbox',

        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 0,
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel'
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 0,
            html: 'O meri jaan'
        }, {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            flex: 1,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            styleHtmlContent : true,

            items: [{
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                html: 'Home Screen'
            }, {
                title: 'Contact',
                iconCls: 'user',
                html: 'Contact Screen'
            }]
        }]
    }
```

This fits into the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha has a difficulty with setting auto height for components inside vbox. I propose you to set height manually when switching tabs. Look at `activeitemchange` listener and `fixHeight` function below:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Test',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.tab.Panel'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            scrollable: 'vertical',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Test',
                docked: 'top'
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 100,
                layout: 'hbox',
                padding: 10,
                defaults: {
                    width: 80,
                    margin: '0 5px'
                },
                items: [{
                    style: {
                        'background-color': '#B1654B'
                    }
                }, {
                    style: {
                        'background-color': '#F79273'
                    }
                }, {
                    style: {
                        'background-color': '#FDC08E'
                    }
                }, {
                    style: {
                        'background-color': '#FFF6B9'
                    }
                },{
                    style: {
                        'background-color': '#99D1B7'
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                height: 0,
                style: {
                    'border': '2px solid #555'
                },
                defaults: {
                    style: {
                        'padding': '10px 5px',
                        'background-color': '#EFFFE0'
                    }
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'tab 1',
                    html: 'panel 1<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'tab 2',
                    html: 'panel 2<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'tab 3',
                    html: 'panel 3<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.'
                }],
                listeners: {
                    activeitemchange: function() {
                        this.fixHeight();
                    },
                    scope: this,
                    order: 'after'
                }
            }]
        }));
        this.fixHeight();
    },

    fixHeight: function() {
        var tabPanel = Ext.Viewport.down('tabpanel'),
            tabBar = tabPanel.down('tabbar'),
            dh = 10,
            h;
        tabPanel.setHeight(0);// reset tab panel height
        h = tabPanel.getActiveItem().element.dom.scrollHeight + tabBar.element.getHeight() + dh;
        tabPanel.setHeight(h);
    }
});
```